# recursive method for a flat xml file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell-2.0

I have a flat xml file. Elements palced in same level, the only way to know how the elements belonging to each other is parentId, like following.

```
<pages>
 <page id="1" parentId="0">
 ...
 </page>
 <page id="2" parentId="1">
  ...
 </page>
 <page id="3" parentId="1">
 ...
 </page>
 <page id="4" parentId="2">
 ...
 </page>
 ...
 ....
</pages>
```

I wanted to make a recursive method to go through all pages and replace them under each other and make it like a real xml (tree structure) using Powershell. Do I need to read whole xml for each element?

Answer (score 0):

I sovled it and this is my solution:

```
function GetName($parentNode)
{
  Write-Host $parentNode.Id " " $parentNode.Name
  $childs = $AMtalatData.Pages.Page | Where-Object {$_.ParentId -eq $parentNode.Id}

  foreach($node in $childs)
  {
    Write-Host "  id="$node.Id " " $node.Name




    $grundChilds = $MyData.Pages.Page | Where-Object {$_.ParentId -eq $node.Id}

    if($grundChilds.Count -gt 0)
    {
        MyFunction-parentNode $node
    }        
  }

}

$myelem= $MyData.Pages.Page | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 12}

MyFunction -parentNode $myelem
```